# Recommended way to render huge PDF Files within browser

Tags: angular, spring-boot, pdf, itext, large-files

Currently working on a project which consist of a Spring Boot Backend and an Angular Frontend.

Users should be able to view their documents embeded within that Angular Frontend. Documents can be about ~1GB and may contain up to 300.000 pages ( serial letters).

Serving these files is not the problem, but rendering it!

I was trying

- [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/intro)
- [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)

already. But it either loads endless  or the browser is very instable and slow

Even the Firefox/Chrome build in PDF-Viewer cant handle it properly.
Is there any other method / plugin I could use?

My alternative would be:

- rendering and serving each page by its own via backend and building a custom UI around it
- Split PDF into x parts and serve these part, so a pdf viewer plugin  could be used. Additionally you would need an additional UI to get through each part.

Is there any best practice already?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to divide the PDF into multiple parts and load it batch by batch.
Had to implement a UI giving me 100 pages each.